# How to filter array of object based on condition React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am new to react js, I searched google, object append, object concatenation, shallow copy, a deep copy are there in JavaScript, But, I can't find out the merge the array of objects into a single array of objects.

How to filter an array of objects based on the type and save the response as a single array of objects?

```
    const options = ["Fruit", "Vegitables", "Drinks"];
        const mainArray=[{
        Type:'Fruit',
        Name:'apple',
        Amount:'20'
        },
        {
        Type:'Fruit',
        Name:'apple',
        Amount:'20'
        },
        {
        Type:'Vegitables',
        Name:'tomoto',
        Amount:'50'
        },
        {
        Type:'Vegitables',
        Name:'onion',
        Amount:'20'
        },
        {
        Type:'Drinks',
        Name:'Milk',
        Amount:'30'
        },
        {
        Type:'Drinks',
        Name:'Juice',
        Amount:'20'
        }
        ]
        ///Filtering By Type
        
        const filterByType=()=>{
        let allMergedData=[];
         selectedtypes?.map((type)=>{
            let mergedData=[];
            let filteredData= mainArray?.filter(x=>x.Type===type.toLowerCase());
            mergedData=[...filteredData];
            allMergedData=[...mergedData, ...filteredData];
         })
         return allMergedData;
        };
        
        return(
        <div>
        {options.map((option) => (
                    <MenuItem key={option} value={name}>
                      <Checkbox value={option}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  checked={selected.includes(option)} />
                      <ListItemText primary={option} />
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
        </div>
        )
```

> Excepted output:

````
    allMergedData:[{
            Type:'Fruit',
            Name:'apple',
            Amount:'20'
            },
            {
            Type:'Fruit',
            Name:'apple',
            Amount:'20'
            },
            {
            Type:'Vegitables',
            Name:'tomoto',
            Amount:'50'
            },
            {
            Type:'Vegitables',
            Name:'onion',
            Amount:'20'
            },]

```
````

Comment: Why do you expect that output? Please may you share a [mcve] of your attempt?

Comment: I need to bind the data into the data table

Comment: Try to use "pure functions". Your `filterByType()` function is using variables defined outside, that's dangerous. Plus, check your expected output, I think it need the type "Drinks" or not? because is on the options array.

Comment: I am sharing CodeSandBox Link. I added the code in code sand box. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-data-table-forked-090e9?file=/src/movies.js

Comment: I got the output in the console log. The three objects I need to merged single array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function could help, edited as your need:

```
function groupBy(arr, criteria) {
  const newObj = arr.reduce(function (acc, currentValue) {
    if (!acc[currentValue[criteria]]) {
      acc[currentValue[criteria]] = [];
    }
    acc[currentValue[criteria]].push(currentValue);
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return newObj;
}
```

Test it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/y9odgtjm/2/

Comment: ok, I will try this.